# How do i give permission to myself to edit files

Tags: permissions, files, users

I am having problem editing a file inside the system directory.

I have been having auto boot check up issues and i just want to remove it , so according to a little research i have to do some file edits like should add

fsck.mode=skip

into the grub.

But i am not able to edit the file because it says i don't have perimission to edit the files.

Comment: You use `sudo` to elevate privileges.  Be aware that the `grub.cfg` file gets re-generated, so changes there tend not to *stick* (survive) long, so being specific as to OS/release & file you're editing may help you achieve what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: Set your `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables to your chosen editor (I use `emacsclient`, but you can pick any editor you want to 
use) and use the `sudoedit` command. Read `man sudoedit`. Also, keep a copy of the unedited, original file.

Comment: can you help me with my bluetooth issue? @waltinator

Answer (score 0):

### How to edit files?

To get permission to edit files you need a `sudo` privilege

i.e. `sudo nano grub.conf` you'll get satisfied.

If you're still not happy with this you could change the permissions using `chmod` stands for change mode of permissions.

`Paste this link in terminal`

```
sudo chmod u+rw grub.conf
```

here `u` is for user `+` indicates the accessible permission of `rw` reading and writing.

Caution/ Warnings :--

Without knowing anything don't edit root files because if you do so your pc will get damage and you don't have another choice to get access of your data.

Thanks For Asking :)